# Translation of an inscription on a Kiddush cup

Tags: translation

[image]

I've had it for months now and its from the 40s.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us! Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?

Comment: This question should be on-topic as it asks about a Kiddush cup.

Answer (score 9):

The inscription reads "L'chaim," and means "to life." It is a [well known toast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haim) in Hebrew/Yiddish.

Comment: Thank you so much