# Help what does this mean?

Tags: hebrew

Need this translated, and what does it mean or say?[image]

Comment: A belated welcome to Mi Yodeya! You should know that, like your [previous question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/104836/), this is likely to be closed, as questions about Hebrew are not necessarily on-topic.

Comment: The other question should be on topic as it asks about a Kiddush cup. This question would need a jewish context to be on topic.

Comment: @Yishai, I would say the other question is not on topic. It is basically a Hebrew language question, where the Hebrew language happens to appear on a kiddush cup. Neither should be encouraged...

Answer (score 4):

If you have a lot of items that you need transliterated / translated, you are unlikely to be able to harness the folks at Mi Yodea.

You can try [Amazon Mechanical Turk](https://www.mturk.com/), make a task of transliterating, and paying a small amount of money to get Hebrew speakers to do this for you.

Comment: Welcome back josh!

Comment: Josh, you're right of course but please remember to help out by voting to close too.

Comment: @doubleaa shouldn't this be a comment?

Comment: IMHO, if the *answer* is consistently something like this, then spam of this sort is likely to occur. So, e.g. @Shalom's answer below encourages further questions.

Comment: Thanks, @DonielF!

Comment: @Yishai Yes, it is. If the question is ever reopened I'll bother to move it.

Answer (score 1):

It says "Satan", but it looks like all the vowels got shifted over by one. What "Satan" means in Hebrew ... is a different question.